# using jquery, convert object of objects into an array, except last value

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

Not sure if the title was descriptive enough so I'll describe my issue a little better here. I am making an AJAX call, in PHP I put together 30 objects, and add in the query I made to the end of the objects. From my understanding, within PHP I can only echo one object and that is what will return in the AJAX response. 
On the PHP Side Looks like this

```
$data = json_encode($data);
echo $data;
```

within my AJAX response i have a data object that will look like this

```
{object, object, object, query:"SELECT * FROM realForeclosure WHERE auctionStatus='SOLD' etc..."}
```

I need my objects to be separate from the query, because I want to loop through the objects and paint them into the UI.

The solution I came up with, was to convert the object of objects into an array, 
Than I need to find the key that = "query" and set that to a variable and pop that out of the array so it is separated.

Is this the best way to do this?
If so what would the code look like, would I use `$.grep` to isolate and remove the query from the original object?

Comment: You might want to look at split(), returns array of substrings, and slice(), look at the negative indices part. On my phone, can't do more.

Comment: Your Javascript object is not valid. All the elements of an object must be of the form `key: value`. The first 3 elements are missing the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create your PHP data like this:

```
$data = array('results' => $results,
              'query' => $query);
```

Then in your Javascript, you can do:

```
var results = response.results;
var query = response.query;
```

Comment: hey Barmar, that is exactly what I needed to do, thanks! now that it is already separated on the PHP side, it is really easy for me to reference it. I was able to do it with JS but pointless to iterate and transform an obj to an array if I dont have too thanks!